# Backbone rebinding events on a view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have two views, one represents a view of clients and the other is the individual client views. I am binding the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events in the client view to fade in and out an overlay on the image. This works fine when it is by itself. However, I am also using a jQuery plugin to do a carousel effect (plugin [here](http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/)). Once that is enabled, my custom events no longer work. Is there any way I can delegate the Client View events after the plugin is initialized? This is my first time using Backbone so I might be doing something else wrong as well.

Here is the code:

```
// Client View
window.ClientView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'li',
  template: _.template($("#client-template").html()),
  className: 'client-thumb',

  events: {
    "mouseenter": "fadeOutOverlay",
    "mouseleave": "fadeInOverlay"
  },

  initialize: function() {
  },

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  },

  fadeOutOverlay: function() {
    $(this.el).find(".slider-image-overlay").fadeOut('fast');
  },

  fadeInOverlay: function() {
    $(this.el).find(".slider-image-overlay").fadeIn('fast');
  }

});

// Clients View
window.ClientsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#clients",

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.bind('all', this.render, this);
  },

  render: function() {
    var $clients = $("<ul class='clearfix'></ul>");
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(client) {
      var view = new ClientView({model: client});
      $clients.append(view.render().el);
    });

    $(this.el).hide().append($clients).fadeIn().scrollingCarousel();

    return this;
  }
});
```

**EDIT**: Here I am trying to `delegateEvents()` on the views that were created (the ones that have the events on them):

```
App.View.ClientsView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: "#clients",

  initialize: function() {
    this.collection.bind('all', this.render, this);
  },

  render: function() {
    var $clients = $("<ul class='clearfix'></ul>");
    var views = [];
    _.each(this.collection.models, function(client) {
      var view = new App.View.ClientView({model: client});
      views.push(view); // Store created views in an array...
      $clients.append(view.render().el);
    });

    $(this.el).hide().append($clients).fadeIn().scrollingCarousel({
      // Use the plugin's callback to try to delegate events again
      afterCreateFunction: function() {
        _.each(views, function(view){
          view.delegateEvents();
        });
      }
    });

    return this;
  }
});
```

Tried this but doesn't seem to work? Am I doing it right? I think that the plugin is doing more than I think to the DOM. It looks like it is touching the elements I am trying to bind to as well as binding to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. I am unfamiliar with this plugin, doesn't look like it has an unminified version so I can't read it too well.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: May be I'm wrong but you didn't have any event attached to your ClientsView

Comment: if you dont pass a selector to the events object events are bound to the view `el`ement

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can do that using `delegateEvents` method of your view to rebind your events

usage: `myView.delegateEvents()`

reference the documentation http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents for more info

edit:

this plugin binds and unbinds mouseenter/leave without namespacing - open the plugin script and add namespace to the event binding and unbinding.

apply these fixes to every occurence of these and it should be ok even without the `delegateEvents()`

`r.unbind("mouseenter");` => `r.unbind("mouseenter.carousel");`
`r.unbind("mouseleave");` => `r.unbind("mouseleave.carousel");`

`r.mouseenter(function() { ...` => `r.bind('mouseenter.carousel', function() { ...`
`r.mouseleave(function() { ...` => `r.bind('mouseleave.carousel', function() { ...`

Comment: I updated my answer with an edit that tries to `delegateEvents()` but still doesn't work. Probably something to do with the plugin...

Comment: Thanks for the help. Didn't work, the plugin must be doing more than I thought. I'm just going to use regular jQuery delegating in the afterCreate callback for now.